# Car making a groaning sound when it moves?

Tags: noise

Let's be clear-- the sound is *not* coming from the engine.

It's something more along the lines of suspension, maybe? It's like when the car moves, turning or moving forward, whenever the inertia changes, there's a groaning, as though the body of the car were straining against whatever it were mounted on.

I have no idea. Thoughts? Questions?

Comment: Does this occur every time, after an overnight park, or just a short stop?

Comment: Every time the car's inertia changes. During turns, lane changes, stops, starts, increase/decrease in speed.

Answer (score 4):

My best guess would be worn-out rubber bushings in the suspension components. Check the lower control arms, especially where they attach to the shocks, for cracks or complete deterioration.

Answer (score 3):

When's the last time you greased your suspension ball joints?  Unless they're sealed, they should have some zerk fittings on them for a grease gun.  If they are sealed, you can drill a hole in them and attach a fitting, but you'd be better off just replacing them.